# avoid app crash in microservice on http Exception

Tags: exception, nestjs, microservices

I have `Nestjs` microservice app ,

a gateway and users service

connected via **RabbitMQ**

when some **Http Exception** happens in Users service

it cause app to crash

But it is ok on **Rpc Exception**

I think any Http Exception must be catched and

converted to **Rpc Exception** in order to avoid crash.

do you know where and How should It be done ?

or any other better idea to handle this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an exception filter with your own logic of how to serialize your errors, this example I modified from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/exception-filters#inheritance) to catch `HttpException` errors and return them as an observable using `throwError`

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseRpcExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

@Catch()
export class CustomExceptionFilter extends BaseRpcExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
      return throwError(() => exception.getResponse());
    }

    return super.catch(exception, host);
  }
}
```

Then used it on the controller that responds to other microservice

```js
import { Controller, UseFilters, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern, Payload } from '@nestjs/microservices';

import { CustomExceptionFilter } from './custom-exception.filter'

@Controller('users')
@UseFilters(CustomExceptionFilter)
export class UserController {
  @MessagePattern('create.user')
  create(@Payload(ValidationPipe) createUser: CreateUserDTO) {
    return this.userService.create(createUser);
  }
}
```